# MySQL queries take too long, can't understand why?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I use MySQL and have a query that, in principle, should be pretty fast, but that's not the case. In the query I have the use of 2 tables, one weighs 14MB(called b) and the other weighs 106GB(yes, GB)(called p and p2). I tried to filtered as much as possible so that I can fetch the query results quickly, but this query runs for over 15 minutes endlessly until I cancel it. I would love your help to figure out how I can handle this. So this is what the query looks like:

```
SELECT b.code ,p2.result
    FROM b_codes b
    INNER JOIN pass p ON (b.id = p.id)
    INNER JOIN pass p2 ON (b.s = p2.s AND b.tn = p2.tn AND p.t_ta = p2.t_ta AND p2.s = (p.s+1))
    WHERE b.s <> ''
    AND b.id <> 0
    AND p2.date >= '2022-04-24 00:00:00' 
    AND p2.date <= '2022-06-05 23:59:59'
    AND b.j = 'Completed'
    AND b.tn IN ('538')
    GROUP BY b.code, b.id
```

I tried to add the use of indexes, in p2 we have an exact index for each of the fields and the same goes for an index of id for p, but the problem seems to be in the dates of p2 and in group by. I tried to change the dates for the term (between) but that didn't help either. I will be happy for your help!

This is the result of EXPLAIN without the indexes:
[EXPLAIN on query WITHOUT INDEXES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URRvq.png)

First row : b_codes, Second row : p, Third row : p2

This is the result of EXPLAIN with the indexes: [EXPLAIN on query WITH INDEXES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxAOA.png)

Comment: Correct me, if you already have this indexes
Your indexes should be 
1. [index_name]]
columns
- b.s
-b.id
-b.j
b.tn

2.[any_index_name]
column/s
p2.date

Comment: Why are you even using `GROUP BY` here, given that you do not select any aggregate functions?  Also note that MySQL will generally only use one index per table.  So having separate indices on each field in a given table may not help the way you think it does.

Comment: You need an composite index on `b_codes` table ... `(s,id,j,tn)` and try changing the order of condition to `WHERE b.s <> '' AND b.id <> 0 AND b.j = 'Completed' AND b.tn IN ('538')  AND p2.date >= '2022-04-24 00:00:00'  AND p2.date <= '2022-06-05 23:59:59'`

Comment: Those aren't explain plans, they may be ***parts*** of explain plans though.  Please include the ***entire*** explain plan, not just snippets.  Please also include the full definitions for the tables, including all the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me, if you already have this indexes.
You should have indexes like this.
It must be based on what columns you used in your where clause in specific table/s

1. [index_name]]

columns

- b.s
- b.id
- b.j
- b.tn

[any_index_name]
column/s

- p2.date

Comment: How can I add index for WHERE clause? I dont have a specific index for all b table, but I can try to add one for it.

Comment: You might be misunderstood me, what I mean is if you have a query
"select * from table_1 where id=1 and date = '2022-06-29'"
then 
you should create index like this
"CREATE INDEX index_name
ON table_1 (id, date );"

Answer (score 0):

```
b.id <> 0
```

Could that be changed to `b.id > 0`?  Is `id` the `PRIMARY KEY`?  Is it `AUTO_INCREMENT`?  Why might it be "0"?

Suggested index for the smaller table (order of columns is important):

```
b_codes:  INDEX(j, tn, s, code, id)
```

Please show the entire `EXPLAIN`.  (Text is preferrable to image.)

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  For one thing, is `id` the `PRIMARY KEY` of either `b` or `id`?  After some more info, I will provide index recommendation for the larger table.

Also, I don't yet know whether to change one of the tests to `(p.s = p2.s-1)`